# SQL difference between two rows having the same id

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to know how to take the difference in value (Val) for two rows having the same ID and return that from a SQL query. The difficulty here is that I was the difference between the second row and the first one, and each ID only has two rows.

I am using SQLite 3.8.6.

Here is what my table looks like:

```
ID   Val   TimeStamp
+---+----+---------------------+
| 2 |  7 | 2015-05-09 12:54:39 |
| 2 |  2 | 2015-05-09 14:48:30 |
| 3 | 16 | 2015-05-09 13:19:57 |
| 3 | 20 | 2015-05-09 15:01:09 |
+---+----+---------------------+
```

I want to end up with:

```
ID   Val   
+---+----+
| 2 |  -5|
| 3 |  4 |
+---+----+
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select
   t1.id,t2.val-t1.val AS [Val]
from table t1
inner join table t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
   AND t1.TimeStamp<t2.Timestamp
```

Comment: what are t1 and t2 in your solution?

Comment: They are table aliases. It is the table you showed on your question.

Comment: @Ghost, knowing that the table I gave comes from a first query, how would you make calls to it?

Comment: @RackhamLeRouge Create a view